# How to get uniqueness of user

Tags: facebook

I'm making facebook photo gallegy voting application and i've found that i have many cheaters. They are voting from many accounts and many different ip addresses(also have many votes from same ip). But the connection between votes are obvious because of timing - 2 to 30 sec one after another.

I need some technique to get user unique info, like browser id, or os serial no or something like that. IP is not an option. Thanx

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has a **verified** option AFAIK. If the user is not verified facebook user, you may count the vote as fake and ignore it.

A facebook user has to register his/her phone number to facebook to be a verified user. This guarantees(almost) that the user is a real person and not a fake account.